# How to add OAuth 2.0 providers?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, facebook, oauth-2.0

I could reproduce my bug using servside OAuth2.0 only so it's not javascript and the issue is that I must reload to make login / logout take effect and I want it to work without javascript. I have an idea that making logout twice makes logout effective so I could use a custom request handler for /login and/or /logour or just /sessionchange that will do a self.redirect but it's not the clean solution. Maybe you can take a look at the code and see why I must logout twice ie I must reload and can I workaround this using a `self.redirect` ? Am I using cookies the right way, the new cookie, or do I get it mixed up? I'm doing this both for the [website](http://koolbusiness.com) and for the [FB app](http://apps.facebook.com/koolbusiness). I'll be glad if you can come with any suggestion. There's a background of 2 related questions from before I removed the Javascript. And BTW should I use class Facebook or facebook.py? I think I commented out where the old cookie is set and that this will be correct once OAuth 2.0 handles my authentication serverside. Can you comment or answer? Thank you in advance if you can review and comment.

[How to make my welcome text appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775320/how-to-make-my-welcome-text-appear)

[How to make this page reload on login / logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747687/how-to-make-this-page-reload-on-login-logout)

[Why my strange results rendering the user object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735502/why-my-strange-results-rendering-the-user-object)

[login.html](http://www.koolbusiness.com/login)

```
{% load i18n %}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>  <title>{% trans "Log in" %}</title> 

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{{analytics}}']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({

      appId      : '164355773607006', // App ID

      channelURL : '//WWW.KOOLBUSINESS.COM/static/channel.html', // Channel File

      status     : true, // check login status

      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session

      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0

      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML

    });



    // Additional initialization code here

  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously

  (function(d){

     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;

     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";

     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);

   }(document));

</script>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164355773607006&redirect_uri=http://{{host}}"><img src="/_/img/loginwithfacebook.png"></a>

<a href="/_ah/login_redir?claimid=google.com/accounts/o8/id&continue=http://{{host}}"><img src="/_/img/loginwithgoogle.png"></a><br>{% if user %}<a href="{{ logout_url }}" class="logout">Logout Google</a>{% endif %} 

{% if current_user %}<a href="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://{{host}}&access_token={{current_user.access_token}}" onclick="FB.logout()">Logout Facebook</a> {% endif %}

{% if current_user %}<a href="/logout" onclick="FB.logout();">Logout Facebook JS</a> {% endif %}

</body>

</html>


class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    facebook = None
    user = None
    csrf_protect = True

    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
            self._current_user = None
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(
                self.request.cookies, facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
        logging.debug("logging cookie"+str(cookie))
            if cookie:
                # Store a local instance of the user data so we don't need
                # a round-trip to Facebook on every request
                user = FBUser.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                logging.debug("user "+str(user))
                logging.debug("username "+str(user.name))

                if not user:
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    user = FBUser(key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                                id=str(profile["id"]),
                                name=profile["name"],
                                profile_url=profile["link"],
                                access_token=cookie["access_token"])
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                self._current_user = user
        return self._current_user
   def initialize(self, request, response):
        """General initialization for every request"""
        super(BaseHandler, self).initialize(request, response)

        try:
            self.init_facebook()
            self.init_csrf()
            self.response.headers[u'P3P'] = u'CP=HONK' # iframe cookies in IE
        except Exception, ex:
            self.log_exception(ex)
            raise

    def handle_exception(self, ex, debug_mode):
        """Invoked for unhandled exceptions by webapp"""
        self.log_exception(ex)
        self.render(u'error',
            trace=traceback.format_exc(), debug_mode=debug_mode)

    def log_exception(self, ex):
        """Internal logging handler to reduce some App Engine noise in errors"""
        msg = ((str(ex) or ex.__class__.__name__) +
                u': \n' + traceback.format_exc())
        if isinstance(ex, urlfetch.DownloadError) or \
           isinstance(ex, DeadlineExceededError) or \
           isinstance(ex, CsrfException) or \
           isinstance(ex, taskqueue.TransientError):
            logging.warn(msg)
        else:
            logging.error(msg)

    def set_cookie(self, name, value, expires=None):

        if value is None:
            value = 'deleted'
            expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=-50000)
        jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        jar[name] = value
        jar[name]['path'] = u'/'
        if expires:
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.timedelta):
                expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
                expires = expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
            jar[name]['expires'] = expires
        self.response.headers.add_header(*jar.output().split(u': ', 1))

    def render(self, name, **data):
        """Render a template"""
        if not data:
            data = {}
        data[u'js_conf'] = json.dumps({
            u'appId': facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            u'canvasName': facebookconf.FACEBOOK_CANVAS_NAME,
            u'userIdOnServer': self.user.id if self.user else None,
        })
        data[u'logged_in_user'] = self.user
        data[u'message'] = self.get_message()
        data[u'csrf_token'] = self.csrf_token
        data[u'canvas_name'] = facebookconf.FACEBOOK_CANVAS_NAME
        data[u'current_user']=self.current_user 
        data[u'user']=users.get_current_user()
        data[u'facebook_app_id']=facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID
    user = users.get_current_user()
        data[u'logout_url']=users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164355773607006&redirect_uri='+self.request.uri
        host=os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST', os.environ['SERVER_NAME'])
        data[u'host']=host
        if host.find('.br') > 0:
        logo = 'Montao.com.br'
            logo_url = '/_/img/montao_small.gif'
            analytics = 'UA-637933-12'
        domain = None
    else:
        logo = 'Koolbusiness.com'
            logo_url = '/_/img/kool_business.png'
            analytics = 'UA-3492973-18'
        domain = 'koolbusiness'

        data[u'domain']=domain
        data[u'analytics']=analytics
        data[u'logo']=logo
        data[u'logo_url']=logo_url
        data[u'admin']=users.is_current_user_admin()
        if user:
            data[u'greeting'] = ("Welcome, %s! (<a href=\"%s\">sign out</a>)" %
                        (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/")))


        self.response.out.write(template.render(
            os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', name + '.html'),
            data))

    def init_facebook(self):

        facebook = Facebook()
        user = None

        # initial facebook request comes in as a POST with a signed_request
        if u'signed_request' in self.request.POST:
            facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.get('signed_request'))
            # we reset the method to GET because a request from facebook with a
            # signed_request uses POST for security reasons, despite it
            # actually being a GET. in webapp causes loss of request.POST data.
            self.request.method = u'GET'
            #self.set_cookie(
                #'u', facebook.user_cookie, datetime.timedelta(minutes=1440))
        elif 'u' in self.request.cookies:
            facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.cookies.get('u'))

        # try to load or create a user object
        if facebook.user_id:
            user = FBUser.get_by_key_name(facebook.user_id)
            if user:
                # update stored access_token
                if facebook.access_token and \
                        facebook.access_token != user.access_token:
                    user.access_token = facebook.access_token
                    user.put()
                # refresh data if we failed in doing so after a realtime ping
                if user.dirty:
                    user.refresh_data()
                # restore stored access_token if necessary
                if not facebook.access_token:
                    facebook.access_token = user.access_token

            if not user and facebook.access_token:
                me = facebook.api(u'/me', {u'fields': _USER_FIELDS})
                try:
                    friends = [user[u'id'] for user in me[u'friends'][u'data']]
                    user = FBUser(key_name=facebook.user_id,
                        id=facebook.user_id, friends=friends,
                        access_token=facebook.access_token, name=me[u'name'],
                        email=me.get(u'email'), picture=me[u'picture'])
                    user.put()
                except KeyError, ex:
                    pass # ignore if can't get the minimum fields

        self.facebook = facebook
        self.user = user

    def init_csrf(self):
        """Issue and handle CSRF token as necessary"""
        self.csrf_token = self.request.cookies.get(u'c')
        if not self.csrf_token:
            self.csrf_token = str(uuid4())[:8]
            self.set_cookie('c', self.csrf_token)
        if self.request.method == u'POST' and self.csrf_protect and \
                self.csrf_token != self.request.POST.get(u'_csrf_token'):
            raise CsrfException(u'Missing or invalid CSRF token.')

    def set_message(self, **obj):
        """Simple message support"""
        self.set_cookie('m', base64.b64encode(json.dumps(obj)) if obj else None)

    def get_message(self):
        """Get and clear the current message"""
        message = self.request.cookies.get(u'm')
        if message:
            self.set_message() # clear the current cookie
            return json.loads(base64.b64decode(message))



class Facebook(object):
    """Wraps the Facebook specific logic"""
    def __init__(self, app_id=facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            app_secret=facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET):
        self.app_id = app_id
        self.app_secret = app_secret
        self.user_id = None
        self.access_token = None
        self.signed_request = {}

    def api(self, path, params=None, method=u'GET', domain=u'graph'):
        """Make API calls"""
        if not params:
            params = {}
        params[u'method'] = method
        if u'access_token' not in params and self.access_token:
            params[u'access_token'] = self.access_token
        result = json.loads(urlfetch.fetch(
            url=u'https://' + domain + u'.facebook.com' + path,
            payload=urllib.urlencode(params),
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            headers={
                u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
            .content)
        if isinstance(result, dict) and u'error' in result:
            raise FacebookApiError(result)
        return result

    def load_signed_request(self, signed_request):
        """Load the user state from a signed_request value"""
        try:
            sig, payload = signed_request.split(u'.', 1)
            sig = self.base64_url_decode(sig)
            data = json.loads(self.base64_url_decode(payload))

            expected_sig = hmac.new(
                self.app_secret, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

            # allow the signed_request to function for upto 1 day
            if sig == expected_sig and \
                    data[u'issued_at'] > (time.time() - 86400):
                self.signed_request = data
                self.user_id = data.get(u'user_id')
                self.access_token = data.get(u'oauth_token')
        except ValueError, ex:
            pass # ignore if can't split on dot

    @property
    def user_cookie(self):
        """Generate a signed_request value based on current state"""
        if not self.user_id:
            return
        payload = self.base64_url_encode(json.dumps({
            u'user_id': self.user_id,
            u'issued_at': str(int(time.time())),
        }))
        sig = self.base64_url_encode(hmac.new(
            self.app_secret, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
        return sig + '.' + payload

    @staticmethod
    def base64_url_decode(data):
        data = data.encode(u'ascii')
        data += '=' * (4 - (len(data) % 4))
        return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

    @staticmethod
    def base64_url_encode(data):
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data).rstrip('=')
```

facebook.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2010 Facebook
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
# not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
# a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
# WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
# License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

"""Python client library for the Facebook Platform.

This client library is designed to support the Graph API and the official
Facebook JavaScript SDK, which is the canonical way to implement
Facebook authentication. Read more about the Graph API at
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api. You can download the Facebook
JavaScript SDK at http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/.

If your application is using Google AppEngine's webapp framework, your
usage of this module might look like this:

    user = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, key, secret)
    if user:
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(user["access_token"])
        profile = graph.get_object("me")
        friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")

"""
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
import cgi
import hashlib
import time
import urllib
#from django.utils import translation, simplejson as json
# Find a JSON parser

try:
    # For Google AppEngine 
    from django.utils import simplejson
    _parse_json = lambda s: simplejson.loads(s)
except ImportError:
    try:
        import simplejson
        _parse_json = lambda s: simplejson.loads(s)
    except ImportError:
        import json
        _parse_json = lambda s: json.loads(s)


class GraphAPI(object):
    """A client for the Facebook Graph API.

    See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api for complete documentation
    for the API.

    The Graph API is made up of the objects in Facebook (e.g., people, pages,
    events, photos) and the connections between them (e.g., friends,
    photo tags, and event RSVPs). This client provides access to those
    primitive types in a generic way. For example, given an OAuth access
    token, this will fetch the profile of the active user and the list
    of the user's friends:

       graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
       user = graph.get_object("me")
       friends = graph.get_connections(user["id"], "friends")

    You can see a list of all of the objects and connections supported
    by the API at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/.

    You can obtain an access token via OAuth or by using the Facebook
    JavaScript SDK. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
    for details.

    If you are using the JavaScript SDK, you can use the
    get_user_from_cookie() method below to get the OAuth access token
    for the active user from the cookie saved by the SDK.
    """
    def __init__(self, access_token=None):
        self.access_token = access_token

    def get_object(self, id, **args):
        """Fetchs the given object from the graph."""
        return self.request(id, args)

    def get_objects(self, ids, **args):
        """Fetchs all of the given object from the graph.

        We return a map from ID to object. If any of the IDs are invalid,
        we raise an exception.
        """
        args["ids"] = ",".join(ids)
        return self.request("", args)

    def get_connections(self, id, connection_name, **args):
        """Fetchs the connections for given object."""
        return self.request(id + "/" + connection_name, args)

    def put_object(self, parent_object, connection_name, **data):
        """Writes the given object to the graph, connected to the given parent.

        For example,

            graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="Hello, world")

        writes "Hello, world" to the active user's wall. Likewise, this
        will comment on a the first post of the active user's feed:

            feed = graph.get_connections("me", "feed")
            post = feed["data"][0]
            graph.put_object(post["id"], "comments", message="First!")

        See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing for all of
        the supported writeable objects.

        Most write operations require extended permissions. For example,
        publishing wall posts requires the "publish_stream" permission. See
        http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for details about
        extended permissions.
        """
        assert self.access_token, "Write operations require an access token"
        return self.request(parent_object + "/" + connection_name, post_args=data)

    def put_wall_post(self, message, attachment={}, profile_id="me"):
        """Writes a wall post to the given profile's wall.

        We default to writing to the authenticated user's wall if no
        profile_id is specified.

        attachment adds a structured attachment to the status message being
        posted to the Wall. It should be a dictionary of the form:

            {"name": "Link name"
             "link": "http://www.example.com/",
             "caption": "{*actor*} posted a new review",
             "description": "This is a longer description of the attachment",
             "picture": "http://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg"}

        """
        return self.put_object(profile_id, "feed", message=message, **attachment)

    def put_comment(self, object_id, message):
        """Writes the given comment on the given post."""
        return self.put_object(object_id, "comments", message=message)

    def put_like(self, object_id):
        """Likes the given post."""
        return self.put_object(object_id, "likes")

    def delete_object(self, id):
        """Deletes the object with the given ID from the graph."""
        self.request(id, post_args={"method": "delete"})

    def request(self, path, args=None, post_args=None):
        """Fetches the given path in the Graph API.

        We translate args to a valid query string. If post_args is given,
        we send a POST request to the given path with the given arguments.
        """
        if not args: args = {}
        if self.access_token:
            if post_args is not None:
                post_args["access_token"] = self.access_token
            else:
                args["access_token"] = self.access_token
        post_data = None if post_args is None else urllib.urlencode(post_args)
        file = urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/" + path + "?" +
                              urllib.urlencode(args), post_data)
        try:
            response = _parse_json(file.read())
        finally:
            file.close()
        if response.get("error"):
            raise GraphAPIError(response["error"]["type"],
                                response["error"]["message"])
        return response


class GraphAPIError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, type, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)
        self.type = type


##### NEXT TWO FUNCTIONS PULLED FROM https://github.com/jgorset/facepy/blob/master/facepy/signed_request.py

import base64
import hmac


def urlsafe_b64decode(str):
    """Perform Base 64 decoding for strings with missing padding."""

    l = len(str)
    pl = l % 4
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(str.ljust(l+pl, "="))


def parse_signed_request(signed_request, secret):
    """
    Parse signed_request given by Facebook (usually via POST),
    decrypt with app secret.

    Arguments:
    signed_request -- Facebook's signed request given through POST
    secret -- Application's app_secret required to decrpyt signed_request
    """

    if "." in signed_request:
        esig, payload = signed_request.split(".")
    else:
        return {}

    sig = urlsafe_b64decode(str(esig))
    data = _parse_json(urlsafe_b64decode(str(payload)))

    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        raise SignedRequestError("Pyload is not a json string!")
        return {}

    if data["algorithm"].upper() == "HMAC-SHA256":
        if hmac.new(secret, payload, hashlib.sha256).digest() == sig:
            return data

    else:
        raise SignedRequestError("Not HMAC-SHA256 encrypted!")

    return {}



def get_user_from_cookie(cookies, app_id, app_secret):
    """Parses the cookie set by the official Facebook JavaScript SDK.

    cookies should be a dictionary-like object mapping cookie names to
    cookie values.

    If the user is logged in via Facebook, we return a dictionary with the
    keys "uid" and "access_token". The former is the user's Facebook ID,
    and the latter can be used to make authenticated requests to the Graph API.
    If the user is not logged in, we return None.

    Download the official Facebook JavaScript SDK at
    http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/. Read more about Facebook
    authentication at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.
    """

    cookie = cookies.get("fbsr_" + app_id, "")
    if not cookie:
        return None

    response = parse_signed_request(cookie, app_secret)
    if not response:
        return None

    args = dict(
        code = response['code'],
        client_id = app_id,
        client_secret = app_secret,
        redirect_uri = '',
    )

    file = urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(args))
    try:
        token_response = file.read()
    finally:
        file.close()

    access_token = cgi.parse_qs(token_response)["access_token"][-1]

    return dict(
        uid = response["user_id"],
        access_token = access_token,
    )
```

Some log traces are

```
2011-10-18 18:25:07.912

logging cookie{'access_token': 'AAACVewZBArF4BACUDwnDap5OrQQ5dx0sHEKuPJkIJJ8GdXlYdni5K50xKw6s8BSIDZCpKBtVWF9maHMoJeF9ZCRRYM1zgZD', 'uid': u'32740016'}

D 2011-10-18 18:25:07.925

user <__main__.FBUser object at 0x39d606ae980b528>

D 2011-10-18 18:25:07.925

username Niklas R
```

Now looking at the code that does this it seems to me that I'm confusing the module facebook with the variable facebook where one is the class facebook from the example project and one is the new recommended module facebook.py:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    facebook = None
    user = None
    csrf_protect = True

    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
            self._current_user = None
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(
                self.request.cookies, facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
        logging.debug("logging cookie"+str(cookie))
            if cookie:
                # Store a local instance of the user data so we don't need
                # a round-trip to Facebook on every request
                user = FBUser.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                logging.debug("user "+str(user))
                logging.debug("username "+str(user.name))

                if not user:
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    user = FBUser(key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                                id=str(profile["id"]),
                                name=profile["name"],
                                profile_url=profile["link"],
                                access_token=cookie["access_token"])
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                self._current_user = user
        return self._current_user
```

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what question you're asking here. Try starting by describing what you're trying to achieve, then how you're going about it, then what problems you encounter.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I want to enable a case like http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ with python and make sure cookie and access_token work. I'm either handling the cookie or the OAuth token wrong. I'll try to revise so that the login / logout flow gets possible to follow. The class `Facebook()` is from the app example and the module `facebook.py` is a new version that was recommended here and I think it might do with one, or one for the FB app and one for the appspot app since I'd probably use the Javascript SDK for the FB app and serverside OAuth 2.0 from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to add Facebook as OAuth 2.0 provider: Here's how I make "Login with facebook" for my website with OAuth instead of javascript / cookie this is python only for OAuth 2.0 with Facebook and as far as I can tell it's working:

```
class FBUser(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty()
    access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    picture = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.StringProperty()
    friends = db.StringListProperty()

class I18NPage(I18NHandler):
    def get(self):
    if self.request.get('code'):
          args = dict(
            code = self.request.get('code'),
            client_id = facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            client_secret = facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
            redirect_uri = 'http://www.koolbusiness.com/',
          )
      logging.debug("client_id"+str(args))
          file = urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(args))
          try:
        logging.debug("reading file")
            token_response = file.read()
        logging.debug("read file"+str(token_response))
          finally:
            file.close()
          access_token = cgi.parse_qs(token_response)["access_token"][-1]
          graph = main.GraphAPI(access_token)
          user = graph.get_object("me")   #write the access_token to the datastore
      fbuser = main.FBUser.get_by_key_name(user["id"])
          logging.debug("fbuser "+str(fbuser))

          if not fbuser:
            fbuser = main.FBUser(key_name=str(user["id"]),
                                id=str(user["id"]),
                                name=user["name"],
                                profile_url=user["link"],
                                access_token=access_token)
            fbuser.put()
          elif fbuser.access_token != access_token:
            fbuser.access_token = access_token
            fbuser.put()
```

The login link is

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164355773607006&redirect_uri=http://{{host}}/"><img src="/_/img/loginwithfacebook.png"></a>` that redirects and allows me to pick up the access_token in the method above and logout is straightforward:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://www.koolbusiness.com&access_token={{access_token}}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a>`